# Fill the CALayer with different color when timer reaches to 5 seconds swift ios

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, core-animation, calayer

In my app i am using a third party library which does circular animation just like in the appstore app download animation. i am using the external file which i have placed in my project. it works but when the timer reaches to 5 seconds the fill color should be red. Currently the whole layer red color applies, i want to only apply the portion it has progressed. i am attaching the video and the third party file. Please can anyone help me with this as what changes should i make to the library file or is there better solution

[same video link in case google drive link doesnt work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ytzhpb9atyugq2/Screen%20Recording%202022-07-11%20at%209.21.53%20PM.mp4?dl=0)

[External Library link which i am using](https://github.com/riley2012/circle-timer-ios)

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eePBi4rvL_HpmaFbkLCZf4WLGCreKssu/view?usp=sharing)

[external third file file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DuAapVGeAP1Wlz_d1OhMAk2sTGrKCxlt/view?usp=sharing)

My code snippet that i have tried:

```
func startGamePlayTimer(color: UIColor)
    {
        if !isCardLiftedUp {
            self.circleTimerView.isHidden = false
            self.circleTimerView.timerFillColor = color
            Constants.totalGamePlayTime = 30
            self.circleTimerView.startTimer(duration: CFTimeInterval(Constants.totalGamePlayTime))
        }
       
        if self.gamePlayTimer == nil
        {
            self.gamePlayTimer?.invalidate()
         
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                                                   target: self,
                                                   selector: #selector(updateGamePlayTime),
                                                   userInfo: nil,
                                                   repeats: true)
            timer.tolerance = 0.05
            RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
            self.gamePlayTimer = timer
        }
    }
    
    @objc func updateGamePlayTime()
    {
        if Constants.totalGamePlayTime > 0
        {
            Constants.totalGamePlayTime -= 1
            
            if Constants.totalGamePlayTime < 5
            {
                SoundService.playSound(sound: .turn_timeout)
                self.circleTimerView.timerFillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.stopGamePlayTimer()
        }
    }
```

where circleTimerView is the view which animates as the time progresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `CAKeyframeAnimation` on the `StrokePath`.

I've Update the code in `CircleTimer` View as below. You can modified fill color and time as per your need.

```
 @objc func updateGamePlayTime()
    {
        if Constants.totalGamePlayTime > 0
        {
            Constants.totalGamePlayTime -= 1
            
            if Constants.totalGamePlayTime < 5
            {
                SoundService.playSound(sound: .turn_timeout)
                // self.circleTimerView.timerFillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7) // <- Comment this line 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.stopGamePlayTimer()
        }
    }
```

---

```
open func drawFilled(duration: CFTimeInterval = 5.0) {
    clear()
    if filledLayer == nil {
        let parentLayer = self.layer
        let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.bounds = parentLayer.bounds
        circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: parentLayer.bounds.midX, y: parentLayer.bounds.midY)
        let circleRadius = timerFillDiameter * 0.5
        let circleBounds = CGRect(x: parentLayer.bounds.midX - circleRadius, y: parentLayer.bounds.midY - circleRadius, width: timerFillDiameter, height: timerFillDiameter)
        circleLayer.fillColor = timerFillColor.cgColor
        circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleBounds).cgPath
        
        // CAKeyframeAnimation: Changing Fill Color on when timer reaches 80% of total time

        let strokeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
        strokeAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.80]
        strokeAnimation.values = [timerFillColor.cgColor, timerFillColor.cgColor, timerFillColor.cgColor, UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
        strokeAnimation.duration = duration;
        circleLayer.add(strokeAnimation, forKey: "fillColor")
        
        parentLayer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        filledLayer = circleLayer
    }
}
```

---

```
open func startTimer(duration: CFTimeInterval) {
    drawFilled(duration: duration) // <- Need to pass duration here  
    if useMask {
        runMaskAnimation(duration: duration)
    } else {
        runDrawAnimation(duration: duration)
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

*CAKeyframeAnimation:*

- You specify the keyframe values using the `values` and `keyTimes` properties.

For example:

```
let colorKeyframeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")

colorKeyframeAnimation.values = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                                 UIColor.green.cgColor,
                                 UIColor.blue.cgColor]
colorKeyframeAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
colorKeyframeAnimation.duration = 2
```

This animation will run for the `2.0` duration.

- We have 3 values and 3 keyTimes in this example.
- 0 is the initial point and 1 be the last point.
- It shows which associated values will reflect at particular interval [keyTimes] during the animation.

i.e:

`KeyTime 0.5` -> (2 * 0.5) -> At `1 sec` during animation -> `UIColor.green.cgColor` will be shown.

Now to answer your question from the comments, Suppose we have timer of 25 seconds and we want to show some value for last 10 seconds, we can do:

```
        strokeAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.60]
        strokeAnimation.values = [timerFillColor.cgColor,timerFillColor.cgColor, timerFillColor.cgColor, timerFillColor.cgColor, UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
strokeAnimation.duration = 25.0 // Let's assume duration is 25.0
```

Comment: you mean self.circleTimerView.timerFilledColor = .red right? @Kush Bhavsar

Comment: Nope. You need to comment that piece of code inside `updateGamePlayTime()` and replace `drawFilled` function as above. Please check the updated answer!

Comment: not working i have done as you have said..sharing you the video file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vtby8nkhza7f69/Screen%20Recording%202022-07-11%20at%2011.26.01%20PM.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Also Need to pass the duration `drawFilled(duration: duration)` inside `startTimer` method. :)